# How to hook up data from local json to achieve search with autocomplete text in list?

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to implement input search feature wherein typing a search text will display suggested text and user can select relevant text from list and hit search button to proceed to corresponding screen. The suggested text is in `local json` and I added it under under `assets/` folder and in `pubspec.yaml`.
The search textfield is:

[image]

The code for above is:

```
new TextField(
            style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0),
          cursorColor: Colors.green,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: Container(
              width: 85.0,
              height: 60.0,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: new IconButton(
                icon: new Image.asset('assets/search_icon_ivory.png',color: Colors.white, height: 18.0,),
                onPressed: () {
                },
              ),
            ),
          fillColor: Colors.black,
            contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 30.0, 10.0, 20.0),
            filled: true,
            hintText: 'What Do You Need Help With?',
            hintStyle: new TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white
            )
        )
        )
```

The local json data sample is:
[image]

I want to achieve above using `autocomplete_textfield` package which I've installed and imported and referring [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/autocomplete_textfield#-example-tab-) example.

I would like to know how to get started with this and integrate parsing from local json, hook that data using `autocomplete_textfield` package to achieve my goal. I haven't done parsing json in flutter yet so looking for guidance on how to do that.
The end result I am looking for is like this:

[image]
[image]

***************** Edit **************

I am now able to parse data from `local json` and display it in a `listView` using a demo app. For it, I created a new model class `services.dart' as below:

```
class Categories {
  String serviceCategory;
  String servCategoryDesc;
  int id;
  String autocompleteterm;
  String category;
  String desc;

  Categories({
    this.serviceCategory,
    this.servCategoryDesc,
    this.id,
    this.autocompleteterm,
    this.category,
    this.desc
  });

  factory Categories.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Categories(
        serviceCategory:parsedJson['serviceCategory'] as String,
        servCategoryDesc: parsedJson['serviceCategoryDesc'] as String,
        id: parsedJson['serviceCategoryId'],
        autocompleteterm: parsedJson['autocompleteTerm'] as String,
        category: parsedJson['category'] as String,
        desc: parsedJson['description'] as String
    );
  }
}
```

Used `builder` function to retrieve and display value in `listview` as below:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Load local JSON file"),
        ),
        body: new Container(
            child: new Center(
              // Use future builder and DefaultAssetBundle to load the local JSON file
                child: new FutureBuilder(
                  future: DefaultAssetBundle
                      .of(context)
                      .loadString('assets/services.json'),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    // Decode the JSON
                    Map data = json.decode(snapshot.data
                        .toString());
                    print(data);
                    final List<Categories> items = (data['data'] as List).map((i) => new Categories.fromJson(i)).toList();
                    for (final item in items) {
                      print(item.category);

                      return new ListView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return new Card(
                            child: new Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Text('Service Category: ' + items[index].category),
                                new Text('Category' + items[index].categoryDesc),
                                new Text('Auto complete term' + items[index].autocompleteterm),
                                new Text('Desc' + items[index].desc)
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }
                  }

    )
    )
    )
    );
  }
}
```

In my target app, added required code that uses `autocomplete_textfield` package that shows a static list of suggestions as of now :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    textField = new AutoCompleteTextField<String>
      (style: new TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0),
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: Container(
              width: 85.0,
              height: 60.0,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: new IconButton(
                icon: new Image.asset('assets/search_icon_ivory.png',color: Colors.white,
                  height: 18.0,),
                onPressed: (){},
              ),
            ),
            fillColor: Colors.black,
            contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 30.0, 10.0, 20.0),
            filled: true,
            hintText: 'What Do You Need Help With ?',
            hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white
            )
        ),
        submitOnSuggestionTap: true,
        clearOnSubmit: true,
        textChanged: (item){
          currentText = item;
        },
        textSubmitted: (item) {
          setState(() {
            currentText = item;
          });
        },
        key: key,
        suggestions: suggestions,
        itemBuilder: (context, item) {
          return new Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: new Text(item));
        },
        itemSorter: (a, b) {
          return a.compareTo(b);
        },
        itemFilter: (item, query) {
          return item.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase());
        });

    Column body = new Column(children: [
      new GestureDetector(
        child: new ListTile(
          title: textField,
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (currentText != "") {
                    added.add(currentText);
                    textField.clear();
                    currentText = "";
                  }
                });
              }
              )
      )
    ]
    );

    body.children.addAll(added.map((item) {
      return new ListTile(
          title: new Text(item)
      );
    }));

    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF13212C),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(''),
        ),
        drawer: appDrawer(),
        body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              textField
```

Above code shows in UI as below:

[image]

I now would like to know how to hook the `builder` function retrieving json data in my target app, so that instead of static list of strings, the dropdown would show suggestions from json (as posted in my original question's screenshot).

Comment: I'd recommend first following [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51) to see how to translate your json data into a list of objects which you can then use the `autocomplete_textfield`.

Comment: I am now able to parse data from local json and display its data in `listView` using demo app. I now would like to know how to hook up that data as part of suggestions. I updated my OP with latest code. @SnakeyHips

Comment: Can you show me a code example how to use the list of objects with `autocomplete_textfield` as you suggested above  ? @SnakeyHips

Comment: I'll give it a go tomorrow :)

Comment: Almost got it working but the `textSubmitted` method only casts the item as String and won't let you change it to a custom class. Maybe give [material_search](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/material_search) as it seems this one is just too limited.

Comment: I did look at `material_search` but it was before I learnt about `autocomplete` package and decided to go with latter due to ease of use. Could you share what you came up with ? I'll give it a shot too. @SnakeyHips

Comment: [Sure here you go](https://pastebin.com/N02RNLPM). Everything works until you tap onto an option which then breaks it as the `textSubmitted` assumes the item is a String and won't let you change this.

Comment: Nice..I am going to take a look at it now. Appreciate your help in this to get this far. @SnakeyHips

Comment: I tried to use your code in my target code and facing few compile time errors. Also, it seems the code you shared is missing some part such as `categories: await Category.loadCategories()`. I couldn't find `loadCategories()` method and what does it contain. Could you share that as well ?  Also, this is my current code https://gist.github.com/DK15/b15f60127d705065d8b435c79a0964c1. I highlighted lines of code where I am getting errors. Can you take a look ? @SnakeyHips

Comment: The answer for this OP can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53534197/autocomplete-suggestion-and-search-using-json-data/53537545?noredirect=1#comment93944548_53537545)

Answer (score 0):

If you found doing this manually it too much, this is actually a flutter [package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_typeahead) that does this. There are two examples on the package site too.

Do be warned, this is currently a bug in the package (I have raised a PR to fix it but the package owner has been too busy to review any PR recently). Depending on how you use it, the bug may not affect you.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the package but I think `autocomplete_textfield` better suits for my requirement.